# Continuity of $1/f(x)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and that $f(x) \geq c > 0$ for some constant $c$. Prove that $1/f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $x,y\in[a,b]$. Note that 
$$
\left|\frac{1}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{f(y)}\right|=\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{f(x)f(y)}\right|=\frac{\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|}{\left|f(x)\right|\left|f(y)\right|}\leq\frac{\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|}{c^{2}}.
$$
Can you figure out the rest?

Comment: I think so, but just to clarify, this is part of a delta-epsilon proof?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous and non-zero on $[a,b]$, then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f(x)}=\frac{1}{f(x_{0})}$$

Comment: (OP has probably not yet learned that limits and continuous functions "commute"; +1 though)